# Load boost::uuid from bytes in c++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-uuid

I use `.data()` to get 16 bytes data array.
Later I write it to a file and I want to load it back to a `uuid` variable.
Should I just perform memory copy to the variable as :  (c++11)

```
boost::uuids::uuid uuid = boost::uuids::random_generator()();
char[16] data;
std::copy_n(&uuid, 16, data); // copy to data
std::copy_n(data, 16, &uuid); // copy from data (?)
```

Comment: Can you please show more code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? For example, it would help a lot if we knew what `data` and `uuid` is (we can *guess* but we don't actually *know*).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, i've added more specific example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, whenever you find yourself wondering how to use Boost classes, there's the docs:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html

```
{ // example using memcpy
    unsigned char uuid_data[16];
    // fill uuid_data

    boost::uuids::uuid u;

    memcpy(&u, uuid_data, 16);
}

{ // example using aggregate initializers
    boost::uuids::uuid u =
    { 0x12 ,0x34, 0x56, 0x78
    , 0x90, 0xab
    , 0xcd, 0xef
    , 0x12, 0x34
    , 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef
    };
}
```

Since `memcpy` works I expect `copy_n` will work also.

Comment: Thank you, I did read the docs, apparently I missed that part.